# Splitting a file in Java

Tags: java, split, bufferedreader

To read file into a list, create a new class called ListUtils and write a method called 
public static ListElement readMP3List(String fileName) throws IOException
which will take the name of the file to be read and return the head of a linked list containing the the objects that the file.
In readMP3List, you should open fileName using the classes java.io.BufferedReader and java.io.FileReader and read one line at a time. Each line you should break apart into its fileName, artist, etc., and then use these values to populate a new MP3Info object. Then you make a new ListElement object containing the MP3Info object you just made and put it onto your list.

So far I've got:

```
public class ListUtils{

    public static ListElement readMP3List(String fileName) throws IOExeption{
    {
            // takes name of file  to be read
            // returns the head of Linkedlist
            File file = new File("random_sample.tsv");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String first= br.readLine();
    }
```

The file has multiple lines of names,artist,etc in which I have to split to. I'm really confused on how to use the split(regex) in order to accomplish this.

An example of the file is this:
   fileName  artist  songName  album  trackNum  numSeconds  year  genre \n

Comment: Do they have a common boundary character? As in, are they separated by commas or some common symbol? `artist, name, etc`

Comment: It's separated by white space followed by a newline for the next line of information

Comment: Should be simple enough then, did you look at the docs for split? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Comment: Yes but I'm having a difficult time understanding it and using inside my code.

Comment: If this is homework, please add homework tag to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
String fist=  "fileName artist songName album trackNum numSeconds";

String[] data = fist.split(" ");//whitespace if tab replace with "\t"

String fileName = data[0];
String artist = data[1];
String songName = data[2];
String album = data[3];
String trackNum = data[4];
String numSeconds = data[4];
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say this is homework? Anyway, here is a push in the right direction: given that your file seems to have the extension `tsv`, I can only assume your values are separated by tabs. For splitting by tabs, look into the using [split(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) with `\t`.

*Note: you're not using the `fileName` that is passed in :)*